# If $K$ and $F$ are monotone, when is $I+KF$ monotone?

Tags: operator-theory, fixed-point-theorems

It is known that if $K$ and $F$ are monotone,  that $I+KF$ may not be monotone.  For example,  if $F(x,y)=(x+y, y-x) $ and $K(u,v)=(u+2v, v-2u)$ then $F$ and $K$ are monotone.  However,  $I+KF$ is not monotone. 
Question: What is the sufficient condition for the composotion of the two maps to be monotone?  Or can the mapping $I+KF$  be written as the composition of some other mappings that are Monotone?

Comment: In what sense are $K$ and $F$ 'monotone'?

Comment: What do you mean by $I+KF$? The multiplication is not defined in your example.